# Scapy: Is it possible to manually set the destination MAC address of ARP packets?

Tags: python, scapy, mac-address, arp, data-link-layer

Using python with Scapy, I have no problems changing the MAC address destination of the packets using the following sample code:

```
packet = Ether(dst=[MAC address])/IP()......
```

However, when I try to do the same with ARP like this:

```
packet = Ether(dst=[MAC address])/ARP(......
```

The packet does not get sent out. Is it because ARP is already a layer 2 protocol? If thats the case, is there any possibility of manually changing the destination MAC of an ARP packet?

Comment: So, you are curious about just changing `dst=`?   I mean i have it as a hardcoded string, but if i extract them, i would see no reason why it couldnt be globally changed.  I use that in my get_mac_address calls though, as i use the static string to help determining the target ip address' mac addr.  When doing arp poisoning, i will pass in a target mac, which correlates to the tar ip address.   I think you would want to have it be a proper pairing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sendp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="10.250.0.145", pdst="10.250.0.129"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).